# react-router-dom push() function not available in asyn/await actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-router, redux-thunk

So the title is pretty descriptive, the error i'm getting is:

```
actions.js:392 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.push) is not a function
    at _callee6$ (webpack:///./src/app/Army/store/actions.js?:392:49)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8001/vendor.js:152705:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://localhost:8001/vendor.js:152943:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:8001/vendor.js:152757:21)
    at step (webpack:///./src/app/Army/store/actions.js?:22:191)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/app/Army/store/actions.js?:22:361)
    at <anonymous>
```

Just a bit of background, I'm using `import 'babel-polyfill';` to do a  asyn/await transpiling and my action looks like this:

```
export const update = (Id, Data, publish) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: BA_UPDATING,
      payload: { Id },
    });

    const lib = await client.then(bfn => bfn);
    const response = await lib.getArmy(null, Data.type, Id, { ...Data, publish });

    dispatch({
      type: BA_UPDATED,
      payload: { Id, publish, response },
    });
    dispatch(push('/Army')); // ERROR.
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: BA_ERROR,
      payload: {
        actions: 'update',
        Id,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

`react-router-dom v4.1.1`

Comment: push is available from react-router-redux